# Mathcad to Matlab - random processes and NPS

Tags: matlab, random, noise, spectrum, mathcad

I'm trying to convert a simple Mathcad file into MATLAB script but results I get are just weird. Is there some kind of difference in rand functions? Am I forgetting something essential that differs those two environments?

This is how the Mathcad file looks like:

[image]

[image]

And this is code I'm currently using:

```
clear all
clc

N=100;
data=poissrnd(1000,N,N);
data2=zeros(N);
for l=1:N
    for k=1:N
       drozp=zeros(1,3);
       eta_fot=data(l,k);
       for m=1:eta_fot
          ran=rand(1);
          if ran<0.25
              drozp(1)=drozp(1)+1;
          elseif ran>=0.75
              drozp(3)=drozp(3)+1;
          else
              drozp(2)=drozp(2)+1;
          end
       end
       if (k>1) && (k<N)
          data2(l,k)=data2(l,k)+drozp(2);
          data2(l,k-1)=data2(l,k-1)+drozp(1);
          data2(l,k+1)=data2(l,k+1)+drozp(3);
       elseif k==1
          data2(l,k)=data2(l,k)+drozp(2);
          data2(l,N)=data2(l,N)+drozp(1);
          data2(l,k+1)=data2(l,k+1)+drozp(3);
       else
          data2(l,k)=data2(l,k)+drozp(2);
          data2(l,1)=data2(l,1)+drozp(3);
          data2(l,k-1)=data2(l,k-1)+drozp(1);
       end

    end
end

data2 = data2 - mean(data2(:));
data_w = (1/sqrt(N))*fftshift(fft(data2, [], 2));

NPS1=(abs(data_w)).^2;
NPS2=sum(NPS1);
NPS=(1/N)*NPS2;

plot(NPS)
```

Now, I know it can run faster, originally this block:

```
for m=1:eta_fot
          ran=rand(1);
          if ran<0.25
              drozp(1)=drozp(1)+1;
          elseif ran>=0.75
              drozp(3)=drozp(3)+1;
          else
              drozp(2)=drozp(2)+1;
          end
       end
```

looked like this:

```
[~,R] = histc(rand(1,eta_fot),cumsum([0;w(:)./sum(w)]));
R=a(R);
drozp=histc(R,a)
```

where:

```
a=1:3;
w=[0.25,0.5,0.25];
```

However I tried to get closer to the Mathcad file. Then again results I'm getting (no matter which way I do it) look just bad. See picture below.

[image]

The only way I could get results similar to those from Mathcad file is by changing whole rand loop to a 'rigid' `drozp(1)=0.25*eta_fot`, `drozp(2)=0.5*eta_fot` and `drozp(3)=0.25*eta_fot` but then it has nothing to do with probability anymore. Then again the rand loop looks (functionally at least) like the one used in Mathcad so I have no idea what is wrong.

Is there something I'm missing? Something I've failed to understand? I'm at a loss.

Comment: They look bad? like with ugly colours? That is just a lot of code, you will have problems convincing anyone to go through it line by line to test if it does the  same thing. Why dont you compare your codes line by line and show us where exactly the differences arise?

Comment: Got a chance to add picture of my results. Also added my thoughts about what seems to be off.

Comment: What are you trying to simulate / check? I presume the NPS = Noise Power Spectrum, but all those quartiles and other calcs look like a long way around to 'prove' some standard probability theorems. You are also likely to get better results from the (vendor/PTC) mathcad forum https://www.ptcusercommunity.com/community/mathcad (despite it being the vendor forum ;-) Many in the community do both mathcad & matlab.